# Prevent other applications from writing to SD card

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdcard

Is there any way of using Java or C++ to prevent all applications from writing to the SD card while my application is performing a write operation? Maybe some Linux system call which can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
You cannot prevent from all applications to write to SDCARD. (Applications have been given equal privileged in Android in un-rooted phone)

Yes if the phone is rooted you can perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent other applications from writing, but you can prevent them from writing to your file using File.SetWritable(). If that's not secure enough, and if the file isn't too big, you could write it to internal storage and then move it to SD.